# Django template loop many-to-many iteration query efficiency

Tags: mysql, django, orm, many-to-many, django-tables2

Models:

```
class ItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(AssetsManager, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(
            models.Prefetch("assignments", queryset=Assignments.objects.select_related("userid")))

class Item(models.Model):
    objects = ItemManager()

    id = UnsignedAutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField('Owner', through='Assignments', through_fields=('itemid', 'userid'))

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self.assignments.select_related("userid").last().userid

class User(models.Model):
    id = UnsignedAutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    item = models.ManyToManyField('Item', through='Assignments', through_fields=('userid', 'itemid'))

class Assignments(models.Model):
    id = UnsignedAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    userid = models.ForeignKey('User', default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    itemid = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='assignments')
```

In my template I am trying to iterate over the `Item` queryset while also displaying the `owner`. The problem is that a new SQL query will be made for every step of the loop.

Template loop:

```
{% if item_list %}
    {% for item in item_list %}
        {{item}} - {{item.owner}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The view is a `ListView` where the queryset is "Item.objects.filter(Q(id__gte=1) & Q(id__lte=5))". The `context_object_name` is `item_list`.

Using Django Debug Toolbar I notice the following:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `Assignments` LEFT OUTER JOIN `User` ON (`Assignments`.`UserId` = `User`.`Id`) WHERE `Assignments`.`ItemId` IN (1, 3, 5, 2, 4)
```

This query corresponds to `{% if item_list %}`

Then a new query is made for every iteration:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `Assignments` LEFT OUTER JOIN `User` ON (`Assignments`.`UserId` = `User`.`Id`) WHERE `Assignments`.`ItemId` = 1 ORDER BY `Assignments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

which corresponds to `{{item}} - {{item.owner}}`.

The above example is a simplification I made for testing. I am actually having this issue with django-tables2.

I have tried to make all sorts of querysets, using prefetch_related, Prefetch object in different combinations, but it's never used. Everytime a new query will be sent to the database.

Is there a way to optimize this iteration?

Comment: Use `.prefetch_related`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am using it.